# Initialize all controls on each page of multi-page userform

Tags: vba, initialization, userform, multipage

I'm trying to make a form with a lot of pages. So far it works ok and I added the controls from the code.  Now I'm adding all the validations in the comboboxes in at Initialization but what I want to do is to load the Controls when I change the page. So when I start the form the controls should be loaded for page 1, when I click on Page 2 of the Multipage to load it's components.

The issue i'm facing is when I run, 1st page is not initialized, when 2nd page is clicked its initialized, but, when I switch back to page 1, its initialized.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialze()
   me.MultiPage1.value=0
End Sub

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
   Select Case MultiPage1.SelectedItem.index
   Case 0
      cbWorker.list=array("A","B","C")
      cbCountry.list=array("x","y","z")
   Case 1
      cbStatus.list=array("A","B","C","D")
      cbCommission.list=array(1,2,"x","y","z")
   End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I didn’t initialise the 3rd page which was on the form. Thank you!